# FB.api post strips app_data from link to tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I have created a FB Tab Application that posts a message to the user's wall using the JS FB.api.  The link that is posted to the wall is a link to the FB Tab with some parameters added using app_data.  This worked fine until a few days ago. Now FB is stripping the app_data parameters from the link before posting on the wall, thus posting a link to just to the tab without the parameters.  How do I get FB to post the link with parameters?

```
function postToRecipient() {
    var opts = {
        message: Message,
        name: Name,
        picture: 'http://test.com/images/image.jpg',
        link: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename?sk=app_xxxxxxxxx&app_data=certificate%3dxxxxxxxxx',
        caption: 'caption'
    };
    var callback = function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response.error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success');
        }
    };
    FB.api('/' + recipId + '/feed', 'post', opts, callback);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a solution, but I created a bug report for this issue on facebook.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/478041282206513

Comment: There's another bug report about the same... http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/322852237799370/

Answer (score 0):

The app_data feature itself is still working. I had the same problem and solved temporarily with a simple redirect passing through app_data.